# How to show a one-way if-then relationship?

Tags: regression, correlation, continuous-data

Ordinary least squares regression usually makes assumptions about the residuals that imply an "if and only if" relationship.  Viz. if x is large then y is large and vice versa.

I have gathered some data and suspect a one-way if-then relationship.  Viz. if x is large then y is large but the converse does not hold.

What statistical techniques are appropriate to measure the strength of a correlation in this scenario?

Comment: Your question isn't especially clear. Is there a particular sense in which the converse doesn't hold? For example, one way for it to not hold is to have a relationship that decreases and then increases. Another way to have it not hold is to have a relationship that's flat until about 2/3 of the way across, and then an increasing relationship. A third -- very different -- way is to have a large spread at small x (between small and large values) and a small spread at large x (only large values) so that all the points lay within a triangle. I'd tend to use a different measure for the third way.

Comment: @GlenB This is a good point.  My problem is bounded below by 0, and if y is large then x is large, but when x is small then y will be small.  So I suspect the third case: data in a convex hull(ish) of {(0,0); (x_1,0); (x_1, y_1)}.  Mayyyybe uniformly? Any suggestions for triangley data in the uniform, non-uniform or non-parametric cases?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a measure of causality, but one technique you could look into is [granger causality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) assuming that you're dealing with time-series data.